# Handling a Player in Different Screens?

Tags: java, libgdx, screen

I'm trying to neatly separate methods in a player to handle multiple different screens it will be in.

For instance in my 'world' screen I want to render the top down texture of a player and control their X and Y movement with WASD. However, in the 'battle' screen I want to render the player's side view and control their attacks with WASD.

```
public class Player {
    
    public void renderInScreen1(){...topdown...}
    public void controlInScreen1(){...Move X and Y...}

    public void renderInScreen2(){...Sideview...}
    public void controlInScreen2(){...Control attacks...}

}
```

Is there a pattern or something that could help organize the separate methods my player would have in different screens?

Comment: i would name methods differently like `renderInTopdown`. If you really want to sort the behavior, add a inner classes like `Topdown` and `Sideview` witch would take an player object and perform tasks.

Comment: This how I was thinking of doing it, I didn't think of passing a player object along. That helps quite a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to neatly sort your methods, you can devide them into subclases that would act as components. You end up with shorter method names (if you like that) and cleaner code, though creating components needs some setup as you can see here:

```
public class Player {
    // seting up
    public Topdown topdown = new Topdown(this);
    public SideView sideView = new SideView(this);

    public static class Topdown extends Component {
        public Topdown(Player p) {
            super(p);
        }
         
        // simple names
        public void render() {}
        public void control() {}
    }

    public static class SideView extends Component {
        public SideView(Player p) {
            super(p);
        }

        public void render() {}
        public void control() {}
    }

    // this again shortens the name and documentates your code, you don't have to
    // include "Component" in your component names though it still will be apparent that 
    // class is component
    public static class Component {
        Player p;
        public Component(Player p) {
            this.p = p;
        }
    }
}
```

you the end up with this kind of api calls:

```java
player.sideView.control()
player.sideView.render()
// and so on
```